# CSS/jquery bugs in responsive website

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsiveness

let me start off by saying I'm a very novice coder, but i have done thorough searches on here and other places before asking anything....and I basically know what's wrong with my website, but nothing I have tried so far has seemed to work.

I'm making a 'gaming clan' one pager website for my friend as my first official live website....I decided to use a modified bootstrap theme instead of starting from scratch since I'm still very new at this....

the website url is [www.darknessmilitia.com](http://www.darknessmilitia.com)

One of the main problems I've been having from the very beginning is that when you click on any of the links in the nav, it stays 'active' color even when you continue scrolling down the page, and if you accidentally double click the link, the scrolling gets all glitched out for a few seconds, almost like you are playing tug-of-war with the jquery scrolling animation....

All of the other bugs I have spotted are on the mobile viewport only.

1.The roster panel/table gets cut short when viewed sideways on mobile device

2. Can't figure out how to make the roster collapse upward while in 'unsticky' mode, since its at the bottom of the page when you first load in....if this isn't possible I want to somehow make it barely below the viewport and force them to click the button to scroll down first and stick the nav on top.

3.the navigation menu on mobile doesn't close once a link has been clicked....its not that much of a problem until you try to log-in, the modal gets put behind the nav menu. I suppose I could just change the z-index of the modal, but I would prefer to make it go away when a link is clicked.

I apologize in advance if my code is a bit of a mess, I'm trying my best :(

Thanks for reading, any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your code in your question please, that is, your HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It's much easier to help you if we can see some neatly formatted code in the question without having to trawl through the source code of a linked website.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking about that.....I've read up on the ways you are supposed to format code on here, but I must be doing something wrong....would pasting it to codeply or jsbin be any better?

Answer (score 0):

**Elliot Tregoning** Hi there.
It sounds like this **[single page nav](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/)** will help you here.
It will change the nav when clicked or when you scroll to each location on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! I have a feeling the fact that both the theme and stickynav plugin have scrollspy and jquery animations, they might be conflicting with eachother...problem is that was the only nav I was able to find that would actually work how i wanted...thanks for the link I'll check it out right now. :)